# Example remesh almost planar patches fails for complex meshes

Tags: cgal

When running the example remesh almost planar patches some meshes gives me errors or empty mesh.

Tried different meshes, with different parameters for cosine_of_maximum_angle and distance, but gives me this error:

CGAL error: precondition violation!
Expression : faces(m_face_graph).size() > 0
File       : D:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Shape_detection/Region_growing/Polygon_mesh/Least_squares_plane_fit_region.h
Line       : 161
Explanation:
Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html

Could it be some defects with the meshes ?

Comment: Please submit an issue [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues)